# How can I resolve React Pascal Casing error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using **React** to create a *XML component*  when rendering i get this error on console

> `DeveloperInputs/>` is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React
>   components, or lowercase for HTML elements.

I thought I'm using pascal casing

> `DeveloperInputs`

*here are my imports:*

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";

import React, { Component } from "react";

const DeveloperInputs= props => React.createElement("DeveloperInputs", props);
```

Comment: Is that a recursive component on purpose?

Comment: [createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) : "Create and return a new React element of the given type. **The type argument** can be either a **tag name string** (such as 'div' or 'span'), a React component type (**a class or a function**), or a **React fragment type**." Unless I'm misunderstanding what qualifies as a "tag name string", it looks to me like you're misusing the API by using an inappropriate value `"DeveloperInputs"`

Comment: Indeed... a peek at the react [typescript bindings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts) suggests that use of a `string` type in `createElement` is reserved for native tags such as `div`, `span` etc.

Comment: I am creating XML with react to be clear output should look like: <DeveloperInputs ></DeveloperInputs>

Comment: https://medium.com/@mair.swartz/creating-xml-document-with-react-c6c37f5c608b

Comment: use lowercase naming: DeveloperInputs to developerinputs